# Exemple d'une pièce de théâtre classique disponible et en vers et en prose

Tags: littérature, théatre

J'écoutais récemment une intervention de Georges Forestier au sujet de Molière et plus largement du théâtre classique.

Il mentionne que les tragédies étaient écrites en prose avant d'être versifiées en alexandrins.

Dispose-t-on des deux versions (prose et vers) d'un acte, ou même simplement d'une scène d'une pièce classique ?

Comment: Peux-tu préciser si ta demande concerne des écrits en prose écrits par les auteurs  (Racine, Corneille, Molière) et qui les mettaient ensuite eux-mêmes en vers ? Parce que la quasi majorité des pièces des dramaturges classiques étant inspirés de l’histoire grecque ou romaine, de la mythologie, des fabliaux du Moyen-Âge ou de la Commedia dell'arte,  il existe  des récits en prose antérieurs à leur écriture par les dramaturges du XVIIe siècle.

Comment: @None Oui je parle bien d'un texte en prose écrit par un auteur (Racine, etc.) en vue de sa versification dans un futur immédiat

Comment: @John Je ne crois pas que Molière était un _de_. C'était simplement son nom de scène, sans particule.

Comment: @Frank Œuvres de Monsieur de Molière (1682) (mais ce n'est pas très important)

Comment: @John Intéressant.

Comment: Hors sujet : Baudelaire a réécrit dans ses Petits Poèmes en prose certains de ses poèmes en vers des Fleurs du Mal : [l'invitation au voyage](https://www.kartable.fr/ressources/francais/cours/les-reecritures-du-xviie-siecle-a-nos-jours/17217).;

Comment: @Frank Il s'était autoproclamé *de*, il n'en était pas un. Peu après avoir choisi son nom de scène, dans un acte notarié qui le désigne « Jean-Baptiste Pocquelin, dict Molliere  » il signa « De Moliere ». Article  Wikipedia pour en savoir plus, § *Nom de scène*. Ce dernier  se termine par « ce qui expliquerait qu'il ait commencé par signer « De Molière » et ait été régulièrement désigné comme « le sieur de Molière ». Quelques éditeurs par le passé ont publié les oeuvres de « J. B. Poquelin de Molière », de nos jours il est resté  Molière ou « Jean-Baptiste Poquelin, dit Molière » (La Pléiade).

Comment: @John Je ne connais pas la réponse à votre question. Mais, je me souviens d'avoir lu un avis intéressant sur ce sujet écrit par M. Jean-Louis Barrault, en ce qui concerne l'oeuvre de Racine. Il dit : "Dans les Mémoires sur la vie de J. Racine, Louis écrit à propos de son père: 'Quand il entreprenait une tragédie, il disposait chaque acte en prose.' (...) Il faut se méfier de ce témoignage. En admettant qu'il soit exact, faut-il conclure que Racine n'attachait aucun prix à la forme, à la qualité des alexandrins ?" (BARRAULT, 1946, p. 17).

Comment: @ovide Je ne connaissais pas ce texte, merci pour la référence

Comment: @ovide On peut lire cette citation (souvent reprise) replacée dans son contexte dans *Les Mémoires sur sa vie* (de Louis Racine), https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5457055g/f39.item p.24 (dernière ligne, p.25).

Comment: @None Merci beaucoup !

Comment: @Graffito C'est mieux en vers ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Peut-être dans 'Le Bourgeoise Gentilhomme' de Molière, si je me souviens bien il y a des parties alternant entre la prose et le vers.. mais cela a plus à voir avec la conversation réelle entre les personnages, puisqu’ils parlent littéralement de la pose par rapport au vers dans le discours. C'est seulement une scène au début.
Je ne sais pas si c’est ce que vous demandiez, mais oui.

Comment: La question dit explicitement que Georges Forestier « mentionne que les tragédies étaient écrites en prose avant d'être versifiées en alexandrins », et la personne qui a posé la question a précisé qu'il s'agit d'un texte en prose « en vue de sa versification dans un futur immédiat », cette réponse ne répond donc pas à la question.